# Pandas: Replace empty column values with the non-empty value based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in this format:
[image]

and it needs to be grouped by `DocumentId` and `PersonId` columns and sorted by `StartDate`. Which I doing it like this:
`df = pd.read_csv(path).sort_values(by=["StartDate"]).groupby(["DocumentId", "PersonId"])`

Now if there is row in this group by with DocumentCode `RT` and EndDate not empty, all other rows need to be filled by that end date. So this result dataset should be following:
[image]

I could not figure out a way to do that. I think I can iterate over each groupby subset but how will find the value from the end date and replace it for each row in that subset.

Based on the suggestions to use `bfill()`. I tried putting it as following:

```
df["EndDate"] = (
    df.sort_values(by=["StartDate"])
    .groupby(["DocumentId", "PersonId"])["EndDate"]
    .bfill()
)
```

Above works fine but how can I add the condition for DocumentCode being `RT`?

Comment: I think you are looking for backward fill?  [```pandas.bfill()```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html). You can perform a grouped backward fill that might also be relevant for your case.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston. How will I use condition to check if the DocumentCode is RT only then backfill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the value to use to fill nan inside the apply function.

```py
def fill_end_date(df):
    rt_doc = df[df["DocumentCode"] == "RT"]
    # if there is row in this group by with DocumentCode RT
    if not rt_doc.empty:
        end_date = rt_doc.iloc[0]["EndDate"]
        # and EndDate not empty
        if pd.notnull(end_date):
            # all other rows need to be filled by that end date
            df = df.fillna({"EndDate": end_date})

    return df

df = pd.read_csv(path).sort_values(by=["StartDate"])
df.groupby(["DocumentId", "PersonId"]).apply(fill_end_date).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. The result data frame has added two more duplicate columns, DocumentId and PersonId with just one row populated with values.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the empty cells and replace with `np.nan`, then `fillna` with `method='bfill'`

```
df['EndDate'] = df['EndDate'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x=='' else x)
df['EndDate'].fillna(method = 'bfill', inplace=True)
```

Alternatively you could iterate through the df from last row to first row, and fill in the `EndDate` where necessary:

```
d = df.loc[df.shape[0]-1, 'EndDate']   #initial condition
for i in range(df.shape[0]-1, -1, -1):
    if df.loc[i, 'DocumentCode'] == 'RT':
        d = df.loc[i, 'EndDate']
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'EndDate'] = d
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `DocumentCode` condition with `fillna`?

Comment: I think `bfill` and `ffill` work on a series. To have dependency on other columns, you could use the `for-loop` method and define the conditions in each step of the loop

Comment: I got stuck with the #intial condition itself. It is throwing `KeyError: 4` error

Comment: My bad, it should be `df.shape[0]-1` instead, codes updated